# Django: include external include files

Tags: django, django-templates

Im building a web app which will be part of an existing static website. I'd prefer to use the header and footer from the current site which are static .inc include files.

Is there a way to include these files something like:

{% include 'http://www.mysote.com/inc/footer.inc' %}

Comment: I imagine you want the server to retrieve the file, not the client. Either way, it can take a while to download the file and if that server is down, you've got more problems. I would suggest that you download the file, put it in the templates directory and then include it regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this in Django, but it would be a really easy template tag to write on your own (there's a decent chance someone has already written such a thing, though a quick search didn't turn it up for me).  If you want to go that route, you can do that with a quick `simple_tag` (documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags).  It could probably be as simple as something like:

```
def include_external(url):
    import urllib2
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

register.simple_tag(include_external)


{% include_external 'http://....' %}
```

However, as Umang mentioned, that is potentially problematic--fetching that include file will probably significantly increase your page load time, and you'll guarantee that a failure in your static site will bring down your Django app as well.  If either of those things turns out do be a concern, you could look at caching the header--however, that's adding additional complexity, and you might be better of just copying your header file over each time it's updated.

Comment: This works perfect! 

It also works well with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

The page was lagging a bit so I've went with the option of copying the files into the app each time its updated. 

Thanks
S

Comment: This is a good solution. My only change would be to recommend using the great [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead of the outdated `urllib2` library.