# include static files from django template

Tags: django, templates, static

I'm trying to include a static html page from a django template.

I tried using `{% include the_static.html %}` but this doesn't work for some unknown reason.

the_static.html page is a data page that will be modified often with an html editor.
and my_model has a url to this html and `include` it. But django refuses to find it although I'm sure I've setup the path correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work because the include-tag isn't meant to include external html files but other templates. Check this answer for a possible solution to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7337703/630877

Answer (score 7):

You can write your [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/) to do this.

1. Create a file named `includestatic.py` under `appname/templatetags/`. Also, remember to create `appname/templatetags/__init__.py`, to include the app in settings and to restart the server.
2. `includestatic.py` should have this code:

   ```
   from django import template
   from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
   from django.utils.html import escape

   register = template.Library()

   @register.simple_tag
   def includestatic(path, encoding='UTF-8'):
       file_path = finders.find(path)
       with open(file_path, "r", encoding=encoding) as f:
           string = f.read()
           return escape(string)
   ```
3. To use it in your template, put `{% load includestatic %}` at the top of your template, and then use the tag like `{% includestatic "app/file.txt" %}`.

Comment: Depending on the use-case `mark_safe()` might be better than `escape()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand everything yet...

You've an HTML page served by Django on a given url, let's suppose it to be `http://mydjangodomain/get_the_static/`. This URL is set in the urls.py of your model. Ok, that's normal.

You have a django template for this model. Let's suppose it's defined in a template directory `mytemplates/mymodeltemplates/` and it's called `myfrontpage.html` (since in Django templates are html files).

I guess you've an URL defined in your urls.py to server that front page ? Let's suppose it's `http://mydjangodomain/get_the_front_page/`

---

Now I don't understand how your front page use your static html. Do your final front page html need the static's URL for a "src" attribute or something like it, or do you need to include the static's html into the front page's html ?

In the 1st case, you already have the URL, it's `http://mydjangodomain/get_the_static/` so just use it as if.

In the 2nd case, you don't need the previous URL, get ride of it. Furthermore, put the_static.html in `mytemplates/mymodeltemplates/`. Then you need the `{% include "/mymodeltemplates/the_static.html" %}` tag. If this doesn't work, make sure you've the following in your settings:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

APPLI_ROOT_PATH = "<absolute_path_to_the_application_root_on_your_server>"

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
             '%s/mytemplates' % APPLI_ROOT_PATH,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Yes 2nd case is what I'm after. I am trying to use myapp/data_dir rather than myapp/templates/data_dir . and I added data_dir to STATICFILES_DIR setting. but apparently django isn't finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of resurrecting the dead, but at least with django 1.10, there's a very clean answer here:
http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/static.html

an excerpt from that page:

> Simple Template Inclusion We want to add the Boostrap CSS to all of
>   our templates, but we’d like to avoid repeating ourself: if we add it
>   to each template individually, when we want to make changes (for
>   example, to add another stylesheet) we have to make them to all the
>   files. To solve this, we’ll create a base template that the others
>   will inherit from.
>
> Let’s create base.html in the templates directory of our contacts app.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>

  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> base.html defines the common structure for our pages, and includes a
>   block tag, which other templates can fill in.
>
> We’ll update contact_list.html to extend from base.html and fill in
>   the content block.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contacts</h1>

<ul>
  {% for contact in object_list %}
    <li class="contact">{{ contact }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url "contacts-new" %}">add contact</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Having followed this exactly, I now have a base.html that includes all my style references and the navigation bars/etc, so the html in the `block content` is merely the central contents of each (varying) page.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean that you want to **EXTENDS** the parent template the_static.html?

If yes, you should add below code at the first line of your children template:

```
{% extends "the_static.html" %}
```

Details documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)